# matrix diferential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vectors, rotations

I have the following differential equation: $$ \alpha R^T (d_s^0 \times T_s^0) = \ddot{R}^T d_s^0$$ where $\alpha$ is a constant, $d_s^0 \perp T_s^0$ known constant vectors and $R^T$ is a rotation matrix. I don't know how to solve for $\ddot{R}^T$

Comment: Double dot is some notation for double derative wrt time..? Could with good to clarify as there can often be a large variation of notation used on this side.

Comment: Yes $\ddot{R^T}$ is the double derivative with respect to time